# How to create array of objects from object of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have such object:

```
  const countriesList = {
  NAC: {
    name: 'NAC'
  },
  LEVANT: {
    name: 'Levant'
  },
  GCC: {
    name: 'Gulf Cooperation Council',
    iso2: 'GC',
    code: '96'
  },
  AF: {
    name: "Afghanistan",
    iso2: "AF",
    code: "93"
  },
  AL: {
    name: "Albania",
    iso2: "AL",
    code: "355"
  },
}
```

It's `object`, not `array` and it's important. I want to create new array, which is gonna look like that:

```
const result = [
  {NAC: 'NAC'},
  {LEVANT: 'Levant'},
  {GCC: 'Gulf Cooperation Council'},
  {AF: "Afghanistan"},
  {AL: "Albania"}
]
```

I was trying to do something like that:

```
for (let value in countriesList) {
  let temp = {
    value: countriesList[value]['name']
  }
  this.countries.push(temp)
  temp = {}
}
```

But instead of keys in array of objects I got `value`. How can I do that?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
const countriesList = {
  NAC: {
    name: 'NAC'
  },
  LEVANT: {
    name: 'Levant'
  },
  GCC: {
    name: 'Gulf Cooperation Council',
    iso2: 'GC',
    code: '96'
  },
  AF: {
    name: "Afghanistan",
    iso2: "AF",
    code: "93"
  },
  AL: {
    name: "Albania",
    iso2: "AL",
    code: "355"
  },
}
const res = Object.entries(countriesList).map(([key, {name}])=>({[key]: name}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Object.keys` then map to the `name` property:

```
Object.keys(countriesList).map(x => ({[x]: countriesList[x].name}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Create and similar Array of Object with all the Keys.

```
const countryList = Object.entries(countriesList).map((e) => ( { [e[0]]: e[1] } ));
```

This Will Return Like This

```
[
{
  NAC: {
    name: 'NAC'
  },
  LEVANT: {
    name: 'Levant'
  },
  GCC: {
    name: 'Gulf Cooperation Council',
    iso2: 'GC',
    code: '96'
  },
  AF: {
    name: "Afghanistan",
    iso2: "AF",
    code: "93"
  },
  AL: {
    name: "Albania",
    iso2: "AL",
    code: "355"
  },
}
]
```